# Youtube client that still works?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, flash, youtube, client

I've tried [minitube](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/minitube/+bug/1230355) and [totem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer0.10/+bug/1043950), both of them are broken, which one isn't?
There is an old machine on which flash is too laggy. I hope that native client will fix that. And it needs to be able to search videos by itself, no need for instructions on how to download videos separately or open videos in players just with links from browser.

Comment: Regarding Minitube: Did you take care to install the vlc phonon backend or the gstreamer phonon backend instead of the dummy backend? I don't have any ubuntu PC with minitube, but on my Debian and Gentoo machines it's working like a charm...

Comment: I don't know any other standalone clients for Youtube, BUT, if you install the VLC browser plugin, you can replace the Flash player on Youtube by VLC with a greasemonkey script: https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/87011
This also works with other media player plugins, but I figured that VLC is the one with the most easy to use hardware acceleration, which is quite useful on slower computers.

Comment: yeah, that one helped, add it as an answer please :)

Comment: Which part? Viewtube or the text about the phonon backend for minitube?

Comment: I'm guessing OP meant the VLC solution :)

Comment: yes, ViewTube :)

Comment: As of April 2014 there is no YouTube client in Ubuntu repositories that works.

Comment: Minitube works for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Minitube was updated: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/07/minitube-2-2-playback-fixes-unsubcribe
It's not broken anymore.

Answer (score 1):

OK so the thread IS a bit old - however - there IS another option - SMTube http://smtube.sourceforge.net/

It ought not to be overlooked as an excellent solution.

source-code and PPA link available at the project's site.

Comment: You could improve your answer by [edit]ing it and including the most important facts like a short description and installation guide to your post. This makes sure your answer is still useful even if the link will disappear. It also makes it easier for future readers to quickly find the important information without jumping through several sites. Thank you!